# replace strings in multiple lines

Tags: powershell, replace

After I gci I got the output below:

```
C:\mine\this is the filename I want to keep -blah blah.csv:11:"Windows User","BrftD","Bledaf","Internal user"
C:\mine\it is a different filename I want to keep -bleh blih.csv:12:"Windows User","BrftD","Bledaf","Internal user"
```

I need a replace to replace anything before "\" and after "-" till ":" with '"' and '",' so the output would be

```
"this is the filename I want to keep","Windows User","BrftD","Bledaf","Internal user"
"it is a different filename I want to keep","Windows User","BrftD","Bledaf","Internal user"
```

The script is:

```
gci *.csv | Select-String -pattern '"Windows User"'|Set-Content csvdatacol.csv
Get-Content csvdatacol.csv
```

Comment: Are you sure that that's *one* multiline string? `Get-ChildItem` (alias `gci`) does not produce output that's formatted like that - can you show us exactly what command you ran?

Comment: I edited the post :)

Comment: Assign the output to a variable, rather than doing Set-Content/Get-Content. Then use Select-Object to grab the file name and the line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you

```
Get-ChildItem *.csv |
  Select-String -Pattern '"Windows User"' | 
  % { '"{0}",{1}' -f ($_.FileName -replace '-.*', '').TrimEnd(), $_.Line }
```